# How to right align a picture?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

Question is very simple. I want to \includegraphics and align it to the right, while having some text or items on the left.
Is there a simple command for this??

**Edit** 
Here is what I did from previous answers/comments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame {
      \frametitle{name}
     \noindent
 \parbox{5cm}{some text}
     \hfill
       \rule{2cm}{3cm}
}
\end{document}
```

This creates a space for the picture on the right and a line of text on the left side, but at the bottom of the picture. I want to align it to start from the top of the picture. Which command should I use?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can just use `\raggedleft inside the `figure` environment. If you're using any packages (despite `graphicx`) a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be very helpful.

Comment: @Ronny No, no extra packages, I am learning very basic tricks. Thank you, this thing did it. And where should I insert itemize or how can I have few text lines on the left of the picture, but starting from the top to the bottom, aligned to left?

Comment: I didn't get your question, can you update the original post above and provide an MWE? I think `\caption{}` is what you want and for your ideas, have a look at the `floatrow` package. Also, try not to post [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117), but formulate your question in one complete post (use edit above for this one ;) ) to clarify your question.

Comment: Now, that you changed your question and it is clear that you'Re not working on a document but on beamer slides - look at the manual concerning the `columns` and the `column` environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\noindent
\parbox{2cm}{some words}%
\hfill
\includegraphics{...}
```

will put some words flush left and an image flush right on the same line.

To adjust the alignment you can use `[t]` on the `\parbox` so it aligns on its top row and use `\raisebox` to adjust the image. Moving it by its natural height moves the alignment to its top edge but that may be too far: on the second frame the alignment point is one baseline skip down from the top

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame {
      \frametitle{name}
     \noindent
 \parbox[t]{5cm}{some text}
     \hfill
       \raisebox{-\height}{\rule{2cm}{3cm}}

}

\frame {
      \frametitle{name}
     \noindent
 \parbox[t]{5cm}{some text}
     \hfill
       \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}{\rule{2cm}{3cm}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you David. Could you please tell me what \noindent, \parbox{measure} and \hfill mean, so that I can start using them in other occasions? Also is "flush" left/right a common expression for this?

Comment: `\noindent` removes the indent at the start of a paragraph (which is usually `2em`). The `\parbox` makes the text `2cm` in width and after that `hfill` fills the horizontal space, before it adds the image at the end of the line. This works great, if the image is not in a `figure`environment (hence floating).

Comment: they are all standard latex commands (apart from `\includegraphics` which comes from the `graphics` package) `\noindent` stops paragraph indentation, `\parbox` makes a box in which lines are wrapped to the specified width, `\hfill` is `\hspace{\fill}` a horizontal space that stretches as much as needed, and `\includegraphics` includes graphics.

Comment: @Ronny I am still having problems with the text on the left side of the picture. I can not align it to the left and to the top of the picture. Could you people tell me how to do it?

Comment: @Vladimir please do as requested and edit your question to include a _complete_ document that shows the problem. Use `\rule{2cm}{3cm}` or some such size instead of `\includegraphics` to save posting an image to be included. the  position behaviour is the same.

Comment: @Vladimir I edited my answer to that question, but again, please provide a full description of qhat you want and what you tried (in an MWE). Adapting an answer step by step by step is not that nice.

Answer (score 2):

The OP specified his needs, that the left hand side should be a paragraph and the right hand side a justified right image on a beamer slide. Hence one way to accomplish that would be `columns` as demonstrated here

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding of the file
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            Your longish paragraph text here, where you describe stuff and so on
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}\raggedleft
            \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=2cm]{test}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comments I looked at [`floatrow`](http://ctan.unixbrain.com/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf) which enables you to globally (for all pictures) define such a layout. The MWE would be

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding of the file
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % Demo includes test images
\usepackage[justification=raggedleft,%
    capposition=beside,%
    capbesideposition=left%
  ]{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{test} %your image here
\caption{I am the figure description}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Where `graphicx` is loaded with `[demo]` such that this compiles without an image present. The floatrow is set up, such that the images are justified to the right (first option), the caption is put besides the image to the left.

The result looks like

[image: figure aligned right with caption to the left]

To further align the text top left to the figure change the `capbesideposition`-option to `capbesideposition={left,top}`which yields

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ronny. Sorry if I am not clear enough, I barely can make MWE. I only know what I would like to have and that is: two columns on a frame, one with text and another with a picture. I tried first suggestion and for some reason the text on the left was aligned to the bottom of the picture?? Now your suggestion is to put a caption of the picture to the left, which is not what I need- I want a paragraph of text in the left column. Also, I want this for one frame only, not to affect the whole file.

Comment: Then _tell_ that in the first post of the question. By editing your post i just learned now, that you use _beamer_ which you also didn't mention before. Please be more precise in the future.