# Floating an image to the right in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats

I am trying to float an image to the right of some text in a beamer slide. There is a partial example of this already [available on this site, here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105941/how-to-right-align-a-picture) I seem to be struggling to get it right. The text seems to push down so its not aligned with the picture. here is the document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\title[Title]{Title}
\author{Name}
\institute{College}
\date{March 1, 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
      \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Purpose for writing}

    \textbf{\large Labour Government introduces life saving cancer drug} \\
    \noindent
    \parbox[t]{6cm}{
    The labour government this week has made available a new treatment for a
    rare form of cancer. The usage of Medifix\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
    in Public hospitals. The new drug is expected to save as many as 20 lives
    per year.
    }
    \includegraphics[width = 30mm]{BIB201_Genres_of_NT_Family.png}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get, I am trying `pdflatex`:

[image: picture of the output]

PS: Can I draw a box around this (Im trying to create a fictional newspaper article)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The beamer way uses `columns` and `block` environments. You can change the appearance of the block using `\setbeamerfont` and `\setbeamercolor` applied to `block title` and `block body`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\title[Title]{Title}
\author{Name}
\institute{College}
\date{March 1, 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
      \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Purpose for writing}

  \begin{block}{Labour Government introduces life saving cancer drug}

    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
      \column{\dimexpr\linewidth-30mm-5mm}

      The labour government this week has made available a new treatment
      for a rare form of cancer. The usage of
      Medifix\textsuperscript{\textregistered} in Public hospitals. The
      new drug is expected to save as many as 20 lives per year.

      \column{30mm}
      \includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image}

    \end{columns}
  \end{block}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Purpose for writing}

  \setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=green!50!black,fg=white}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=lime!30}
  \begin{block}{Labour Government introduces life saving cancer drug}

    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
      \column{\dimexpr\linewidth-30mm-5mm}

      The labour government this week has made available a new treatment
      for a rare form of cancer. The usage of
      Medifix\textsuperscript{\textregistered} in Public hospitals. The
      new drug is expected to save as many as 20 lives per year.

      \column{30mm}
      \includegraphics[width=30mm]{example-image}

    \end{columns}
  \end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'll just provide you with a starter (at least for the box). The issue of the picture is your use of `[t]` and `\includegraphics` outside of a `\parbox`.

Concerning the box I added `tcolorbox` as package. It's very powerful and has a bunch of options you can try.

[image: beamer and tcolorbox]

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\title[Title]{Title}
\author{Name}
\institute{College}
\date{March 1, 2017}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
          \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Purpose for writing}
        \tcolorbox
        \textbf{\large Labour Government introduces life saving cancer drug}\tcblower
        \parbox{.55\textwidth}{
        The labour government this week has made available a new treatment for a
        rare form of cancer. The usage of Medifix\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
        in Public hospitals. The new drug is expected to save as many as 20 lives
        per year.
        }\hfill\parbox{.4\textwidth}{
            \includegraphics[width = 30mm]{BIB201_Genres_of_NT_Family.png}
        }
        \endtcolorbox
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your `parbox` and your image in a `tabular` (of course, you can adjust the horizontal and vertical alignments as you like):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
    \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
    \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\title[Title]{Title}
\author{Name}
\institute{College}
\date{March 1, 2017}

\begin{document}


    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Purpose for writing}
        \textbf{\large Labour Government introduces life saving cancer drug}
        \begin{table}%
            \flushleft
            \begin{tabular}{@{}m{6cm}m{30mm}@{}}% Of course, you can adjust the width as you like
                \parbox[t]{6cm}{%
                    The labour government this week has made available a new treatment for a
                    rare form of cancer. The usage of Medifix\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
                    in Public hospitals. The new drug is expected to save as many as 20 lives
                    per year. 
                } &
                \includegraphics[width = 30mm]{example-image-a} \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]